# Thread sleep & wakeup on WinOS

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

How can I implement something like pthreads `pthread_cond_signal` on WinOS. I don't want to use the pthreads Win32 port for this as I also support Win64.

I'm working on a task-based system where a client request spawns n-tasks that spawn n-threads on the server. After the client thread has spawned all the server tasks I want it to enter a sleep state or some other thread state that does not consume any system resources. When all the server tasks have completed I want the client thread to be awoken and return the result(s) to the client application.

Edit:
I've thought about waiting for a conditional variable in some shared memory, and check the condvar in a loop, but don't loops consume resources too? I could add a `sleep()` inside the loop but then I won't get the real-time client request & server response - as a task could take 1/1000 of a second (but also multiple seconds).

Comment: I presume by WinOS, you mean Microsoft Windows (of some kind). There is an extensive API for condition variables, with an efficient waiting mechanism (`WaitForMultipleObjects`). Don't reimplement the wheel when it's already in the API

Comment: @Petesh Good point, I have a tendency to do that. It's good to know that there are API methods for this in Windows. Thank you.

Comment: Just to avoid a misunderstanding: **There is a 64bit build of PThreads for Windows available**. The lastest binaries can be downloaded here: ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/dll/x64 (win32 referrs to the API used, which's name indeed is somehow misleading, as depending on the win release it also supports 64bit apps)

Comment: @alk Nice to know - the naming is misleading indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 API supports condition variables on Vista and higher. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the API and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example usage.

[`WakeConditionVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is equivalent to `pthread_cond_signal()` and [`WakeAllConditionVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is equivalent to `pthread_cond_broadcast()`

That said, if you are on VS2012, I'd really recommend that you use the new [C++11 threading library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). It also has support for [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and since running on multiple platforms is important to you, using the standard library could help you eventually merge your codebases.

Comment: I'm using VS 2012 - I will definitly look into the C++ 11 threading library. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Event functions and WaitForMultipleObject etc

more about event functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx#event_functions

more about WaitForSingleObject here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx

more about synchronization in win32 here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx